# JUnit 5 - JDBC statements testing

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, junit5

I've begun learning unit tests. I'm working with JUnit 5 and I'd like to test my method that inserts some data into my database (using JDBC). Here's my code:

**Datasource.java**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Datasource {

    public static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/java";

    private Connection connection;

    public boolean open() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION, "root", "");
            return true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean insertTable() {
        try {
            String query = "INSERT INTO artists(name) VALUES(?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, "Test");
            int result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            if (result == 1) return true;
            return false;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**DatasourceTest.java**

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class DatasourceTest {

    private Datasource datasource;

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        datasource = new Datasource();

        if (!datasource.open()) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void insertTable() {

        assertTrue(datasource.insertTable());

    }

}
```

It works fine but it actually inserts a record into my database, but I what I want to do is to simulate it. Is it possible to achieve that using only JUnit? If not, what do I need? And a simple implementation would be highly appreciated.

EDIT

I found out about a tool called **Mockito**, is it what I need? If so, could anyone show me how to deploy a simple test of my method insertTable()?

Comment: No, it's not possible with only JUnit, because you are testing integration with other system (in this case, database). These kinds of tests usually are not unit tests, they do actually send data to outside system.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov you can test the right insert statements. You can have a look at PowerMockito. Where you can Mock your `Connection` created by static `DriverManager` and validate the `connection.prepareStatement(query)` call with the right insert statement

Comment: @kism3t I can't find any reasonable tutorial on that, could you recommend something, how to use it with JUnit 5 and JDBC?

Comment: @kism3t, but this is still not possible with only JUnit. I also find it silly to write tests that validate if hardcoded string constant is being passed into method or not.

Comment: @BociucH, also, you really might want to rethink that `System.exit(-1)` statement. By using it you mess with JUnit's error reporting system.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov at the current stage it might be an overkill, but if BociucH puts the values through the method-parameter it is valid to test. And even you could mess the insert statement or a colleague. So with a test it will show you if it is all as planed. BocicucH, I will provide some information

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, actually I was wondering if it's a good idea, but I don't want other tests to kick off when the database connection failed. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @BociucH, you should either "assert" that connection is opened (which will fail all tests if its not), or "assume" that connection is opened (which will make tests not pass, but with "assumption broken" failure type). Both classes should be available in your JUnit installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did using mockito to test insetTable method

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;    
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;    

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DatasourceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Datasource datasource;
    @Mock
    Connection connection;
    @Mock
    PreparedStatement stmt;    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        when(connection.prepareStatement(eq("INSERT INTO artists(name) VALUES(?)"))).thenReturn(stmt);
        when(stmt.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(1);

    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertTable() {
        assertTrue(datasource.insertTable());

    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the import for `Datasource `?

Comment: `Datasource` is class under test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DbUnit framework](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html) with an H2 or HSQL Memory Database.

You will open real connections to a memory Database and you could check that the records is saved by using DataSets

Answer (score 0):

So If using [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki) with version 1.6.5 I would test your code as following

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Datasource.class, DriverManager.class, Connection.class })
public class DatasourceTest {

    @Mock
    Connection con;

    @Mock
    PreparedStatement ps;

    @Test
    public void insertTableTest() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
        PowerMockito.when(DriverManager.getConnection(
                Mockito.eq("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/java"),
                Mockito.eq("root"),
                Mockito.eq(""))).thenReturn(con);

        Datasource ds = Mockito.mock(Datasource.class);
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(ds).open();
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(ds).insertTable();

        boolean result = ds.open();
        Assert.assertTrue(result);

        Mockito.when(con.prepareStatement(Mockito.eq("INSERT INTO artists(name) VALUES(?)"))).thenReturn(ps);
        Mockito.when(ps.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(1);

        result = ds.insertTable();
        Assert.assertTrue(result);

        Mockito.verify(ps).setString(Mockito.eq(1), Mockito.eq("Test"));
        Mockito.verify(ps).executeUpdate();
        Mockito.verify(con).prepareStatement(Mockito.eq("INSERT INTO artists(name) VALUES(?)"));

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, many thanks! Is there a way to do the same thing using only **Mockito**, not PowerMockito?

Comment: No, not with your code. If you are using spring and hibernate it would be possible.